# What is the exact meaning of the "a" in the lower limit of the Riemann–Liouville integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, fractional-calculus

$I^{\alpha }f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha ) }\displaystyle\int_{a}^{x}f(t)(x-t)^{\alpha -1}dt$

In this definition of the Riemann–Liouville integral, wikipedia says that "$a$ is an arbitrary but fixed base point". And later it says that "The dependence on the base-point $a$ is often suppressed, and represents a freedom in constant of integration".

In some examples I found that $a$ becomes $0$, $-\infty$, $1$, etc...

I really wanna know what is the exact definition of this "$a$".

Comment: Restating: Choose a point $a$ so that the integrals will all exist.  Any one will do.  For example, I would normally choose $a=0$.  But if $f(t) = 1/t$ you get divergent integrals, so perhaps then I would choose $a=1$.  Choosing two different $a$'s [such that the integrals exist] gives you two results that differ by a constant.

Comment: @GEdgar It is said that Clearly "$I^{1 }$ f is an antiderivative of $f$ (of first order)." So is it implied that $a$ is going to be the zero of the function $F(t)$? in the case of 1/t, $a$ would be $-\infty$?

Comment: We know that an antiderivative of $1/t$ is $\log(t) = \int_1^t ds/s$.  So in that case it is common to take $a=1$.  Thus $a$ is a zero of the antiderivative, not of $f$ itself.

Comment: @GEdgar Yeah... sorry, for $f(t) = \frac{1}{t}$, $a$ is equal to 1... What I meant is for when $F(t) = \frac{1}{t}$ then $a$ would be equal to $-\infty$ right? For when $f(t) = \frac{1}{-x^{2}}$. What I wanna know is that,can I define $a$ as being the zero of the function $F(t)$?

Comment: But what would $a$ be for some function when $F(t)$ does not have a zero? like when $f(t) = -cot(x) csc(x)$?? Because $F(t) = csc(x)$, and $csc(x) = 0$ has no solutions... I just want to understand what is the precise definition of $a$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the meaning of the word "arbitrary"? The word "arbitrary" refers to the fact that which specific value of $a$ you choose literally does not matter (as long as $a$ is a real number: things change if considering $a\to\infty$ or $a\to-\infty$). In practice, which value you choose depends on the application and on context. So contrary to what you are suggesting, you are not restricted to choosing $a$ to be a zero of the function you are integrating, though it necessarily will be a zero of the antiderivative you are choosing to work with.

However, I should point out that if you are integrating the function $$f(t)=\frac1{t},$$ then you cannot choose $a\to-\infty,$ because then the integral diverges. You should choose $a=1$ in that case.

You asked about the *definitoion* of $a,$ but in asking this, you are missing the point. $a$ is arbitrary. It is not defined as anything. You can choose it to be whatever you want it to be, so long as it is in the domain of the function being integrated. So we typically just choose whatever we find most convenient. But we are not obligated to work with a specific value of $a.$ Choice is a matter of convenience, not a matter of mathematical requirement or definition.

You asked about the case where $F$ has no zeroes. But that is nonsensical. By definition, $F$ will always have a $0.$ If $f$ is integrable, then $$F(t)=\int_a^tf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ will always have a zero at $a.$ And again, $a$ is arbitrary. In the case of the function $f(x)=-\cot(x)\csc(x),$ you can have $F(t)=\int_a^t-\cot(x)\csc(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\csc(t)-\csc(a),$ and the value of $a$ is arbitrary: you can choose whatever value of $a$ you want, as long it lies in the same interval $t$ lies in (otherwise, the integral does not exist). Typically, though, the choice that tends to be most convenient in most applications is $a=\frac{\pi}2.$ So typically, you are working with $F(t)=\csc(t)-1,$ not $F(t)=\csc(t).$ There does not exist a situation in which $F(t)=\csc(t),$ it is an impossible situation, since $\csc(a)$ can never be $0.$ So $F$ will always have a zero at $a.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I'm pretty new to this subject, I don't know anything about it yet... I just wondered about it and I thought that this Riemann-Liouville Integral was supposed to result a new function, and this "$a$" was supposed to remove the constant.

Comment: @arbbo It removes the constant from the notation itself, but it is implicitly built into the definition anyway. That is how integration works, after all. There is never a situation where the constant is not there. What changes is just whether it is explicit or implicit. Technically, the definition of the Riemann-Liouville integral notates it as $I_a^{\alpha},$ in order to make the dependence on $a$ more explicit. But also, when you work with these operators, you typically are working with a rather restricted class of functions, in which case, the "best" value of $a$ becomes obvious.

Comment: Ohh, I see... But if we were to generalize it to more functions, could we just not use this $a$? To just get the fractional antiderivative of some function without it having a constant in the answer? Or maybe we could subtract an hypothetical function $\Xi (a)$ that is equal to the antiderivative of the integrand applied to $a$? Sorry if I'm talking rubbish, but does it even make sense?

Comment: @arbbo I am not sure I understand what you are asking.